# Scoping issue with functions and convert to Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm learning how to work with arrow functions and I've tried to convert my code below. There are a scope problem with funcCall and enterKey. I belive that an arrow function should solve this.

```
function pressKey(funcCall, enterKey = 13) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", _onKeyDown);
}
function _onKeyDown(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === enterKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        funcCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us *how* you tried to change to code, otherwise we can't tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Don't forget to call your `pressKey` function, otherwise, the event listener will not be initialized.

Comment: @cmac—nothing to do with *this*, nor is there anything peculiar to arrow functions that "helps" other than providing an opportunity to reduce the code by a few characters. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create `_onKeyDown` inside the scope of `pressKey` so that it has access to `funcCall` and `enterKey` via closure:

```
function pressKey(funcCall, enterKey = 13) {
    function _onKeyDown(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === enterKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            funcCall();
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", _onKeyDown);
}
```

Using arrow functions or not shouldn't matter for that.

Comment: Admittedly, this is probably a better interpretation of what the asker wanted, though this approach is not always possible, if for example, you want `onKeyDown` and `pressKey` to be in separate files.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a closure from partial application, and yes, arrow functions are good for accomplishing this concisely:

```
const _onKeyDown = (funcCall, enterKey) => e => {
    if (e.keyCode === enterKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        funcCall();
    }
};

function pressKey(funcCall, enterKey = 13) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", _onKeyDown(funcCall, enterKey));
}
```

However, as is pointed out by others, this feature is not exclusive to arrow functions, so if you enjoy typing or are stuck without ECMAScript 2015 syntax:

```
function _onKeyDown(funcCall, enterKey) {
    return function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === enterKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            funcCall();
        }
    };
}

function pressKey(funcCall, enterKey = 13) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", _onKeyDown(funcCall, enterKey));
}
```

Comment: I would insert it as a runnable snippet if it was a complete example. The asker did not provide a complete example.

Comment: I missed the second `=>`. I really dislike this style of code for just that reason, Bergi's example is much more readable.

Comment: Agree to disagree! This style provides the wonderful benefit of modularity, while Bergi's answer requires `onKeyDown` to exist inside of `pressKey`'s scope.

Comment: My comment is in regard to the **style**, not the functionality or design.

Comment: @RobG is this better then?